How to collect operational information from the Android system
I currently need to collect operational information from the Android system, including process launch information (including process ID, parent process, launch time), process network requests (process ID, destination IP, port, and request time), and process file access information (process ID, file name, and file data). Does the Android system have built-in logging functions for these? Or are there existing tools that can meet the above requirements?
Additionally, if I need to implement this myself, my current idea is to hook key system functions (such as fork, execve, connect, open, etc.) or write a Linux kernel module for filtering. Can you please advise if my approach is feasible or optimal?
It should be added that the above requirements are to enable the saving of this information into a file or database for easy viewing and analysis.
Thank you.
